# Unable to connect to web socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, websocket, client-server

I'm having trouble connecting to a websocket in Java. My code worked previously when I ran a server endpoint on localhost port 8080, but when I'm trying to connect to a websocket I found online, i'm getting

javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP response from the server [HTTP/1.1 200 OK] did not permit the HTTP upgrade to WebSocket

I tested the ws endpoint by using Simple Websocket client chrome extension and I'm getting a response. So the server is definitely working properly.

My client code:

```
    package clientendpoints;

import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.DeploymentException;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;

//import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@ClientEndpoint
public class MyClientEndpoint {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    Session session = null;
    public MyClientEndpoint(String endpointURI) {
        //start connection 
        javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer container = javax.websocket.ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        try {
            container.connectToServer(this, new URI(endpointURI));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        logger.info("Client onOpen..." + session.getId());
        this.session = session;    
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        logger.info("MyClientEndpoint log: " + message);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
        logger.info(String.format("Session %s close because of %s", session.getId(), closeReason));
    }
```

And I call it with

```
MyClientEndpoint client = new MyClientEndpoint(MY_SECRET_ENDPOINT);
```

Comment: Still looks like the problem is in the server not returning the right type of response. Try connecting to `ws://echo.websocket.org`.

Comment: So maybe it is the server. That link you provided works. Is there anything else that could have gone wrong on the client side or can I definitely conclude that something's wrong with the server?

Comment: Could there be a proxy server in the way?(http://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers)